# Using a Database Scalar-valued Function in Report

Tags: reporting-services, ssms, bids

Being new to using a reporting services tool I have found myself stuck in a few places.  One of which is the following:  All of the reports that are already in the solution that I am adding my report to make use of the following expression to get the Printed Date for the report:

```
Functions.UtcNowToLocalUser(Parameters!utcfactor.Value)
```

However, when I copy over that expression into my report I get an error upon trying to preview the report that says:

```
The Value expression for the textrun 'thatTextbox' contains an error: [BC30451] Name 'Functions' is not declared.
```

I have examined the Report Data window and even the XML for the working reports to try and find some declaration for 'Functions' but it is never declared in any of the other reports.  Furthermore that function is a Scalar-valued Function within the Database that these reports use so I find myself wondering how the other reports make use of it and how can I make use of it?

Note: My database connection is fine as when I preview the report with that expression removed, it connects and displays the information it is supposed to correctly.  Also, the parameter has already been declared and works elsewhere without error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was led to the answer to this by the answer to this question [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/sqlreportingservices/thread/02c605ae-d875-46ea-9a38-fba713c8f092/) and I will go ahead and copy/paste the answer here:

"from your report click on Report 
then choose Report Properties...

From there you will see a CODE tab.  Enter your function here.

The expression of your textbox will be Code.functionName 
Using your example it would be Code.Area(radius)"

So I looked at the CODE tab for one of the other reports and found nothing there but in the assemblies tab I found a reference to a DateTime assembly.  I copied that and pasted it into the references for my report and now it works error free.